# Program crashes when trying to read numbers with scanf

Tags: c, dev-c++

A message like this appears, when i run this code.
Project.exe has stopped working

Some of my other code works, but this seems to throw me an error.

[image]

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    int n1, n2, sum;

    puts("first number");
    scanf("%d", n1);
    fflush(stdin);
    puts("second number");
    scanf("%d", n2);
    sum = n1 + n2;

    printf("%d + %d = %d", n1, n2, sum);

    getch();

}
```

I basically want to add two numbers.

Comment: Please read your compiler's warnings and fix the errors it points out before asking here.

Comment: Wow, I dare not ask what secret name the program you're writing has D:

Comment: The funny thing, is that my compiler did not give me a warning. @Mat

Comment: Then you're not passing it the right flags. `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` should be your minimal set to start with.

Comment: @Mat I don't think he's using gcc, so maybe the warning options are different. A project file is most probably from visual studio

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: question was originally tagged dev-c++, which comes with GCC

Comment: @Mat I see. The tag was removed so I didn't know that

Comment: @mat i added all the flags you mentions, but still no errors

Comment: @user3328692: well, no errors on the fixed version for sure. For the code as you posted it, you'd need a dinosaur version of GCC for it not to warn with those flags.

Comment: @mat what do you mean, my compiler is gcc

Comment: @user3328692: I mean that unless you have an extremely old version of GCC, it will warn you for this error

Comment: @Mat: i am running tdm-gcc 4.8.1 64bit release

Comment: So? That version  **does** warn if you give it the parameters I told you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf` takes the address of the variable in which it stores the input value. You need to change your `scanf` calls to

```
scanf("%d", &n1);
scanf("%d", &n2);
//          ^ note the & operator
```

Also, note that it's undefined behaviour to call `fflush` on an input stream. So, `fflush(stdin)` is not correct. You need to manually read and discard extraneous input left over in the `stdin` stream.

Comment: Thanks for adding explanation to your code snippet. I was scared that you were going to leave it like rev1 :)

Comment: what do you mean by undefined behavior? i am a newbie @ajay

Comment: @user3328692 Undefined behaviour means the code is wrong even though it will compile fine. The result of the code is unpredictable and anything can happen. It may appear to work correctly but it's unreliable. It may crash the next time you run it. Please read more here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior

Comment: @user3328692 Also, go through this - http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html